# route changes address but doesn't do anything

Tags: angular-ui-router

Here are my routes.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signin-callback', component: SigninCallbackComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DatasetListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'datasets',
        component: DatasetListComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'dataset/:datasetId',
        component: DatasetComponent
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

At `/datasets` the page loads and loads the list of *datasets* as expected.

A link

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['dataset', d.DatasetId]">
```

Updated the browser address -- complete with the `id`, but nothing happens.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `children`.
Moving the route objects to be siblings of the parent level makes it work.